# Make dataframe from list of lists but each element a column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists

I would like to create a dataframe from a list of lists where the resulting dataframe has a column for each element and the rows are the individual. It is hard to explain so I will try and produce an example to work on.

Lets say my list is as follows:

```
myList <- list(
  list(L=c(1,2,3),a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,2,3)),
  list(L=c(4,5,6),a=c(4,5,6),b=c(4,5,6)),
  list(L=c(7,8,9),a=c(7,8,9),b=c(7,8,9)))
```

The resulting dataframe would like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ind = c(1,2,3),
  L.1 = c(1,4,7),L.2 = c(2,5,8), L.3 = c(3,6,9),
  a.1 = c(1,4,7),a.2 = c(2,5,8), a.3 = c(3,6,9),
  b.1 = c(1,4,7),b.2 = c(2,5,8), b.3 = c(3,6,9))
```

I have tried using

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, myList))
```

`df <- bind_rows(myList, .id="column_label")`

but these produce three rows per individual not the desired output.

I also tried using:
`df <- bind_cols(myList)`
but this divides the columns to each list.

Any idea how to go about this?

Thanks,
Eve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the names are always a match one-by-one, you can simply do,

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, unlist))
#     L1 L2 L3 a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3
#[1,]  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3
#[2,]  4  5  6  4  5  6  4  5  6
#[3,]  7  8  9  7  8  9  7  8  9
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer - it works perfectly! I have just added ```as.data.frame()``` around your function to make sure its a dataframe :)

Answer (score 2):

One `purrr` option could be:

```
myList %>%
 map_df(~ bind_rows(unlist(.)))

  L1 L2 L3 a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3
1  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3
2  4  5  6  4  5  6  4  5  6
3  7  8  9  7  8  9  7  8  9
```

Including also the ind column, with the addition of `dplyr`:

```
myList %>%
 map_df(~ bind_rows(unlist(.))) %>%
 mutate(ind = 1:n())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I don't often use ```purrr``` so its nice to see this option too!

Answer (score 2):

You could also tranpose after using `sapply()` to `unlist()`:

```
as.data.frame(t(sapply(myList, unlist)))
  L1 L2 L3 a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3
1  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3
2  4  5  6  4  5  6  4  5  6
3  7  8  9  7  8  9  7  8  9
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer-it works! Would you mind clarifyin what the ```t()``` does?

Comment: Sure thing--`t()` tranposes the matrix. If you run it bit-by-bit, you'll see that the results of `sapply()` do what you need, it just needs to be tranposed.

Answer (score 0):

```r
librayr(purrr) # load the purrr library
library(magrittr) # load the magrittr library
myList %>% 
    map(unlist) %>% # for each element of myList, apply the unlist function which makes it a vector of 9 floats.
    map(as.list) %>% # transform this vector into a list
    map_dfr(data.frame) # and then transofrm this list into a data.frame row.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit more? Maybe by explaining the code?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Agree with @Twenty please can you explain what each part does? I have never used ```magittr``` before but looks like it will be a useful tool!

Comment: `magrittr` is indeed a pretty handy library : it provides the pipe `%>%` which allows a syntaxe `x %>% f(y)` which is equivalent to `f(x,y)` or even `x %>% f` which is equivalent to `f(x)`. This allows to pipe functions one into each others. 

On the other hand, `purrr::map` is a awesome function too. You should look at the documentation for both of them.